# Flink : How to execute continuous query on relational database

Tags: java, postgresql, streaming, apache-flink

**Hello,** I want to read data from relational database continuously to get new data. I written code but it executes the select query one time only not executing repeatedly.
Iterator iterates over only the result stream but not executing query multiple time.

```
StreamExecutionEnvironment environment = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    JDBCInputFormatBuilder inputBuilder = JDBCInputFormat.buildJDBCInputFormat()
            .setDrivername(JDBCConfig.DRIVER_CLASS)
            .setDBUrl(JDBCConfig.DB_URL)
            .setQuery(JDBCConfig.SELECT_FROM_SOURCE)
            .setRowTypeInfo(JDBCConfig.ROW_TYPE_INFO);

    SingleOutputStreamOperator<Row> source = environment.createInput(inputBuilder.finish())
            .keyBy(0)
            .fold(null, new FoldFunction<Row, Row>(){
                @Override
                public Row fold(Row row1, Row row) throws Exception {
                    Date dt = (Date) row.getField(2);
                    return row;
                }
            });

    IterativeStream<Row> iteration = source.iterate();
    iteration.closeWith(iteration.filter(new FilterFunction<Row>() {
        @Override
        public boolean filter(Row row) throws Exception {
            if(Integer.parseInt(row.getField(0).toString()) > 0) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }));

    //iteration.print();

    source.writeUsingOutputFormat(JDBCOutputFormat.buildJDBCOutputFormat()
            .setDrivername(JDBCConfig.DRIVER_CLASS)
            .setDBUrl(JDBCConfig.DB_URL)
            .setQuery(JDBCConfig.INSERT_SQL)
            .setSqlTypes(new int[]{Types.BIGINT, Types.VARCHAR, Types.TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIMEZONE})
            .finish());

    environment.execute();
```

Comment: I can't comment on your code above, but [PipelineDB](https://www.pipelinedb.com/) I think is designed to do what you're asking. It's a forked version of Postgres, and there were plans (last I heard) to make it into an extension.

Comment: In general, repeating the same SELECT over and over won't work very well. You'd do better to work with the database's change data capture stream using something like http://debezium.io/.

Comment: How to set sqlTypes of JDBCOutputFormat in flink 1.9.0, Types.BIGINT is TypeInformation type, not int.